# Why non-daemon threads with blocking operations still running after interrupting control thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I can't figure out the fundamental reason about why non-daemon threads ([daemon thread description](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon)) still running after control thread interrupted. Maybe it's not python specific...

I'm expecting such behavior: when I'm interrupting control thread, then every other threads, generated my program, should shutdown too.
But if a thread performs blocking operation (e.g. I/O action), then this thread still running after control thread interrupted.

Python docs says that:

> If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

It's ok - we can communicate with threads through events, signals, etc., using `select()` for non-block such operations and make reacting to events conditions in loops.

But I'd like to know why things go in such way.

**UPDATE:**
I thought it's common problem and code snippet is not really necessary here, but here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import time

def func_with_blocking_operation():
    time.sleep(5)

threading.Thread(target=func_with_blocking_operation).start()
```

Here after interrupting control thread by hitting `Ctrl+C` in control terminal (`SIGINT` signal was sent to control thread), program still running while sleep function not exited.  Maybe it is because non-daemon threads by default `join()`ed in Python?

Thanks

Comment: It would be convenient if you could provide your code snippet too.